How to automate key distribution prior to Ansible being deployed?
How do admins typically distribute Ansible .pub keys to clients in an early environment? Do they just script that can run ssh-copy-id to multiple machines?
I've looked at other forums and users said to use Ansible to distribute keys, but how can you distribute keys if there's not already one on the client? (I'm not that deep into Ansible, I'm just trying to connect the dots)
EDIT:
I created a inventory file for my lab environment called "inv.ini".
Running the command ansible -i inv.ini clients -m ping shot back "Permission Denied" errors for each client within the group. I used ssh-keygen to generate a RSA key for my admin account, and copied them to each client (manually). After this, the above command worked.

Did you add public key on client machines in .ssh/authorized_keys file?

I don't know how other people do it, but what I've usually done is use customised images, which come with my key baked in.

@RomeoNinov I did not, I was just looking into that. I assume this is where the control nodes .pub key should be placed?

@Ambre, correct. To be able to create ssh communication you need public key to be added in .ssh/authorized_keys on the target machine. If you have more than one ssh key you need to to tell the source machine which one to use.

@muru I'm actually happy you said this, I had considered that option and am glad to hear it's actually used. I can definitely research this for myself but can you use ansible to configure and deploy linux server/clients?

@RomeoNinov I am correcting myself, I do in fact have the public key I created for "ansible_admin" copied to the client machine .ssh/authorized_keys file
